# How to update Qlabel with QCombobox without using a pushButton signal

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox

I was wondering how to add or update a qlabel from the combobox automatically. As i change the options in the QComboBox the QLabel should update.

```
convert_options = ["Celcius to Farenheit", "Celcius to Kelvin", "Farenheit to Celcius", "Farenheit to Kelvin", "Kelvin to Celcius", "Kelvin to Farenheit"]   



class Frame(QWidget):
     def __init__(self):
            super(Frame, self).__init__()
            uic.loadUi("temperature_converter.ui", self)
            self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowTitle("Temperature Converter")
    self.comboBox_choices.addItems(convert_options)
    # comboText = self.comboBox_choices.currentText()
    # self.unit_choice(comboText)
    self.button_choices()

# This if statement if used needs a button signal  

def unit_choice(self, comboText):
        if comboText == "Celcius to Farenheit":
            self.label_unit.setText(chr(176) + "C")
        elif comboText == "Celcius to Kelvin":
            self.label_unit.setText(chr(176) + "C")
        elif comboText == "Farenheit to Celcius":
            self.label_unit.setText(chr(176) + "F")
        elif comboText == "Farenheit to Kelvin":
            self.label_unit.setText(chr(176) + "F")
        elif comboText == "Kelvin to Celcius":
            self.label_unit.setText(chr(176) + "K")
        elif comboText == "Kelvin to Farenheit":
            self.label_unit.setText(chr(176) + "K")
```

Answer (score 0):

> void QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(const QString &text)
>
> This signal is sent whenever the currentIndex in the combobox changes either through user interaction or programmatically. The item's text is passed.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


convert_options = ["Celcius to Farenheit", 
                   "Celcius to Kelvin", 
                   "Farenheit to Celcius", 
                   "Farenheit to Kelvin", 
                   "Kelvin to Celcius", 
                   "Kelvin to Farenheit"]   

class Frame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, convert_options ):
        super().__init__()
#        uic.loadUi("temperature_converter.ui", self)

        self.convert_options = convert_options
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        
        self.label_unit = QLabel()
        
        self.comboBox_choices = QComboBox()
        self.comboBox_choices.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.unit_choice)
        self.comboBox_choices.addItems(self.convert_options)
        # comboText = self.comboBox_choices.currentText()
        # self.unit_choice(comboText)
#        self.button_choices()
# This if statement if used needs a button signal  

        self.grid = QGridLayout() 
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_unit, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.comboBox_choices, 1, 0)
        
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

    def unit_choice(self, comboText):
        if comboText == "Celcius to Farenheit":
            self.label_unit.setText("Celcius to Farenheit: {}".format(chr(176) + "C"))
        elif comboText == "Celcius to Kelvin":
            self.label_unit.setText("Celcius to Kelvin: {}".format(chr(176) + "C"))
        elif comboText == "Farenheit to Celcius":
            self.label_unit.setText("Farenheit to Celcius: {}".format(chr(176) + "F"))
        elif comboText == "Farenheit to Kelvin":
            self.label_unit.setText("Farenheit to Kelvin: {}".format(chr(176) + "F"))
        elif comboText == "Kelvin to Celcius":
            self.label_unit.setText("Kelvin to Celcius: {}".format(chr(176) + "K"))
        elif comboText == "Kelvin to Farenheit":
            self.label_unit.setText("Kelvin to Farenheit: {}".format(chr(176) + "K"))
            
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Frame(convert_options)
    w.setWindowTitle(' update a qlabel from the combobox automatically')
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon('im.png'))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]